# spark.shuffle.spill to false but the spilling is still occurring in spark 1.5.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.5

I set spark.shuffle.spill to false but the spilling is still occurring in spark 1.5.0 as I checked executor logs. I searched spark github repo, and see that they are going to ignore this configuration parameter in 1.6.0 and continue spilling anyway if necessary. But I am using 1.5.0, and I am not sure if it's already taking effect in earlier versions.

Comment: I also see this. I understand that spilling is needed at one point, but I varied the  amount of mem to the executor process, but spilling size was unaffected, for vastly different parameter values of memory size, memory fractions, memory spilling. Did you get any wiser in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is drop a limit of amount of memory used for used for shuffling but it doesn't guarantee you can avoid it completely. If amount of memory required for shuffling exceeds amount of available memory data has to be spilled to disk.

1.6.0 introduces unified memory management (See [SPARK-10000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10000)) so limits are no longer meaningful.